# Using string interning to reduce memory usage of a network client

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-interning

I have a network client which processes data from a server.

Data is sent as a series of messages, which itself are key/value collections, similar in concept to HTTP headers (except there's no "message body"), here is a typical one-way message (lines separated by `\r\n`):

```
Response: OK
Channel: 123
Status: OK
Message: Spectrum is green
Author: Gerry Anderson
Foo123: Blargh
```

My protocol client works by reading from the `NetworkStream`, character-by-character using a `StreamReader` and `while( (nc = rdr.Read()) != -1 )` and uses a state-machine parser and a `StringBuilder` instance to populate `Dictionary<String,String>` instances. These Dictionary instances are then saved into in-memory structures for further processing, they generally have a useful lifespan of about 10 minutes each.

My client receives thousands of these messages per hour and the client process is long-lasting - this is a problem because my client process often grows to consume over 2GB of memory all from these `String` instances - I used windbg to see where all the memory was going. This is a problem because the code runs on an Azure VM with only 3.5GB of memory. I see no reason why my program should consume more than a few hundred MB of RAM at most. Often I'll baby-sit the VM and watch the memory-consumption of my process over time and it will steadily grow to about 2GB, then suddenly drop to about 100MB as the GC does its collection run, then it will grow again. The times can vary between GC runs, with no predictability at all.

Because so many of these strings are identical (such as the keys `Response`, `Status`, etc) as well as known-values like `OK` and `Fail` I can use string interning to reduce usage, like so:

```
// In the state-machine parser after having read a Key name:

String key = stringBuilder.ToString();
key = String.Intern( key );

// etc... after reading value
messageDictionary.Add( key, value );
```

The problem is I see room for an additional optimization: `sb.ToString()` is going to allocate a new string instance which will be used for interning, and secondly: interned strings last for the life of the appdomain, and unfortunately some of the keys won't see re-use and would actually waste memory, such as `Foo123` in my protocol example.

One solution I thought is to not use string interning and instead have a class containing `static readonly` string fields which are the known keys and then use normal, non-interned strings - which would be GC'd eventually and so not risk filling up the string intern pool with one-off strings. I would then compare the `StringBuilder` instance to these known strings, and if so, use them instead of calling `sb.ToString()` thus skipping another string allocation.

However, if I do choose to intern every string, the intern pool will keep on growing, and unfortunately .NET doesn't seem to have a `.Chlorinate()` method for the string pool, is there any way to remove single-use strings from the intern pool if I continue with the `String.Intern` approach, or am I better-off using my own static readonly string instances?

Comment: Maybe you can simulate database reference table behavior by having one dictionary with keyname and id and another with id and value? That way you can actually remove keys forever.

Comment: Use your own interning if needed - there is no way to "unintern" strings interned by `string.Intern`. Using codebook lookups is also a decent way to push memory usage down. Note that string constants are automatically interned.

Comment: No, interning isn't the solution to this problem.  And yes, memory consumption should be megabytes, not gigabytes.  There is something seriously wrong in your program, hard to guess what that might be.  Never paper over serious problems.  Starting point is to look at GC collections with Perfmon.exe, a decent memory profiler is better.  Focus on a stuck finalizer thread or pinned objects, you'll want to learn more about "async pinned handles".

Comment: @HansPassant my project does not contain any custom finalizers nor pinned objects.

Comment: @Luaan by "codebook lookups" are you referring to what @nvoigt suggested by converting my dictionaries to `Dictionary<Int32,String>` and then storing the keys in their own `Dictionary<String,Int32>`?

Comment: Of course it does, you are using the Socket class.  Which uses a finalizer.  Any call to BeginReceive pins an object.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah! I didn't think of that. I meant that there is no user-code finalizers being used. I'm using `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream` rather than `Socket` directly, though I appreciate that `TcpClient` wraps `Socket`. Do you think the socket finalizer might be an issue? And if so, what can I do about it?

Comment: You are asking for a solution without knowing anything about the cause of the problem yet.  Can't work of course, do start using that memory profiler.  And no, this is not a bug in Socket, the bug is in your code.

Comment: @Dai Yeah, basically. Although you usually don't need even a dictionary - most often, you could do with a simple array (if you really are working with batches of data). The actual implementation depends a lot on your precise requirements.

Comment: @Dai, have you done the memory profiling? From my experience strings are not the problem, but the code that references them.

Comment: @Mike Unfortunately I couldn't get a memory profiler to work (well, not VS' at least) as the code runs on an Azure VM, and the profilers refuse to work on virtualized machines.

Comment: You can try to use a memory dump (at least take it using task manager) and then WinDBG with SOS. Of course, that does not give you the best picture, but at least something.
AFAIK, http://memprofiler.com/ suports importing memory dumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interning will not help here, for the reasons you have cited. It would actually make things worse, since interned strings are no longer subject to garbage collection. And no, there is no method to remove interned strings from the pool.

You have described GC doing exactly what GC is designed to do, so it is not really clear to me that you actually have a problem. Adopting interning would mean trading garbage collection (which is not a problem) for a constantly-growing memory demand (which is a problem).

If you are concerned that GC doesn't run often enough to keep your memory consumption below some threshold that you have in mind, you might consider monitoring your memory usage and invoking GC.Collect() when you reach that threshold.

If the GC's behavior pattern is actually causing a problem (other than looking strange) then you may want to try switching from the default "workstation" GC mode to "server" GC mode, as they are tuned differently. (But, again, I'm not at all convinced that you actually do have a problem.)

Some of the differences are covered at these two pages:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx#workstation_and_server_garbage_collection

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx

But note that the actual differences change with each release of the framework, because the people responsible for this stuff are perpetually learning and making improvements.

And the GC mode is governed by app config:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165011(v=office.11).aspx

```
<configuration
   <runtime>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You might also find this troubleshooting guide useful, or at least interesting:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764(v=vs.110).aspx#Issue_TooMuchMemory

Comment: After some digging, I found the actual true cause of the high memory usage: there was code that storing every single character received from the connection in a single `StringBuilder` instance (which ended-up owning a gigabyte-sized-string). Not that the suggestions in this QA didn't help either, they did!